# Hiding certain cells to not be included in a final sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now on Excel. I want to know how to hide certain cells to not be in a final sum.

[image: Bean Example]

In my Bean example above, there are dates and there is data in the cells next to it. That data is the amount of beans I have in the coin bank. What I want to do is to somehow for example to ‘display’ the total amount of beans I have on the 21st of Jan without deleting the data in the other cells.

Comment: You can use something like `=SUMIF(A1:A11,"=21-Jan",B1:B11)` for the total for a specific date (assuming your data start at `A1`), or `=SUMIF(A1:A11,"<=22-Jan",B1:B11)` for the first few entries. A date range would need a more complex formulation, since `SUMIF()` can't take compound criteria.

Comment: Others reading your question assume you want to return the value in your second column based on a specific date you specify. If so, what does your mention of "hiding cells" have to do with your question? Please consider providing a new screen-shot that 1) shows us a sample of your desired end result, and 2) includes the row and column headers of the worksheet.

Comment: I entered this formula, =SUMIF(P34:P44,">=22/01/18",Q34:Q44) and it gives me my result! but i want the result between a range so if i ever want to see the bean between the  jan 28th and the Feb 5th i can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` function to add the values of just some cells in a range.

Let's assume that you dates are in the range A2:A12 and the numbers are in the range B2:B12. In cell D2, enter the date you are interested in (21 Jan). Now in another cell enter the formula

```
=SUMIF(A2:A12,D2,B2:B12)
```

This will return the sum of all cells in the range B2:B12 where the corresponding date in A2:A12 is 12 Jan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will help you.  I would put a filter on top of the columns you want to filter in or out.

Then you can use =SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B12) to sum the cells that are visible.  I would enter this formula right above the cells that you want to be summed up.

=SUM(B2:B12)  Will sum everything filtred or not
=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B12)  Subtotal doesn't sum what is not chosen in your filter.